# Splitting metadata inside Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have metadata in a postgresql table that I need to split. So far I have been attempting to use

```
Select col_name from "tbl_name" split_part('QGC|WGPLNW|IR|BBC|FCPC|WGPLNW|ARME|QPC', ", 1 | 2 | 3 | etc...);
```

Out of a table formatted like so:

```
QGC 10''
QGC 10''
QGC 10''
QGC 10''
QGC 12''
QGC 12''
QGC 12''
QGC 12''
QGC 12''
QGC 10''
```

I need only to extract the integers and would like to preserve the acronyms if possible. I have attempted to use the split substring with regex function but haven't found much success, although this is primarily due to my lack of understanding of how to pass substrings inside of queries when dealing with a table. If someone could explain the appropriate syntax in order to perform this task they would help me greatly. Thanks in advance.

Thanks Martin, You are right - I placed this in the wrong section, thanks for your input. Also, you are correct in assuming that the quotes are holdovers from the database and I have corrected them to more accurately represent the data. How would I go about having the topic moved as not to darken the door of gis.stackexchange?

Comment: Is your compound attribute simply of the form "acronym codenum" or is it of the form "acronym codenum''" (with 2 extra single quotes)?  Also, is the fact that it is metadata relevant? It's just string data isn't it? Please **edit** the question (via button between share and flag) for clarity, thanks.

Comment: Good, you've edited the question, but then the comments *should* have come done here. You soon get the hang of things. :-) To move a misplaced Q, needs anyone or you or I to "flag" it so, then wait for a "moderator" to do the actual move. For now, let's just see if we can get your SQL problem sorted. If the whole thing moves, before, during or after, i think no harm's done. Anyway, we're a colorful bunch, so don't worry about darkened doors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at `split_part()` from [PostgreSQL String Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html), and assuming that `column` is the name of the "compound attribute" that is of the form `"acronym codenum"`, then I'd say you should try something like this

```
SELECT 
  split_part (column, ' ', 1) AS acronym,
  split_part (column, ' ', 2) AS codenum
FROM table
```